# Update SQLite: change text and double

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I have DB with a name (TEXT) and an overall (REAL), and i want to change both of them, i created a method witch takes oldName, newName, double oldOverall, double newOverall.

**this is my Update method:**

```
 public void updatePlayerName(String oldName, String newName, double oldOverall, double newOverall) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_PLAYERS + " SET " + COLUMN_PLAYERNAME + " = '" + newName + "' , " + COLUMN_OVERALL + " = " + newOverall +
            " WHERE " + COLUMN_PLAYERNAME + " = '" + oldName + "' , " + COLUMN_OVERALL + " = " + oldOverall + ";");
    Log.d(TAG, "UPDATE '" + oldName + "' from " + TABLE_PLAYERS + " to " + newName);
}
```

while i am trying to update i get this error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE players SET playername = 'Ben' , playeroverall = 6.0 WHERE playername = 'Guy' , playeroverall = 5.0;

i assume it's the **","** sign, but when I change it to **AND**, the method updates my DB incorrectly, for example:

> if i want to update **"A", 3.0** to **"B", 4.5** it updates to "0", 3.0.

Comment: what do you mean it updates incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public void updatePlayerName(String oldName,String newName,double oldOverall, double newOverallName) {
    String ss = String.valueOf(oldOverall);
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_PLAYERNAME , newName);
contentValues.put(COLUMN_OVERALL , newOverall);
            db.update(TABLE_PLAYERS , contentValues, COLUMN_PLAYERNAME + " = ?"+" AND "+COLUMN_OVERALL+ " = ?", new String[]{oldName,ss });
            db.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the issue with the ',' you must use **AND** in the **WHERE** clause.

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_PLAYERS + " SET " + COLUMN_PLAYERNAME + " = '" + newName + "' , " + COLUMN_OVERALL + " = " + newOverall +
        " WHERE " + COLUMN_PLAYERNAME + " = '" + oldName + "' AND " + COLUMN_OVERALL + " = " + oldOverall + ";");
```

Regarding not updating correctly, what do you mean?

Comment: when i used AND, the method was compiling, 
but the name became '0, and the overall haven't change.
@Bapusaheb Shinde already solved the peoblem

Comment: He was using AND in both the SET and the WHERE clauses.

Comment: Oh OK ... Well I told him just to use in the WHERE clause :)